# Trouble building clara rules dynamically using instaparse

Tags: clojure, rule-engine, clojure-java-interop, plumatic-schema, instaparse

I followed this example [Insta Declarative DSL](http://www.toomuchcode.org/blog/2015/11/14/insta-declarative-dsls) where we use Clara with instaparse to use a DSL and generate rules.

everything works for me as expected but one issue. I am not able to access the variable binding from the condition expressing in lhs and use it in rhs. 
For example, here is the code snippet from the above example.

```
(def shopping-transforms
  {:NUMBER #(Integer/parseInt %)
   :OPERATOR operators
   :FACTTYPE fact-types
   :CONDITION (fn [fact-type field operator value]
                {:type fact-type
                 :constraints [(list operator (symbol field) value)]})

   ;; Convert promotion strings to keywords.
   :PROMOTIONTYPE keyword

   :DISCOUNT (fn [name percent & conditions]
               {:name name
                :lhs conditions
                :rhs `(insert! (->Discount ~name ~percent))})

   :PROMOTION (fn [name promotion-type & conditions]
                {:name name
                 :lhs conditions
                 :rhs `(insert! (->Promotion ~name ~promotion-type))})})
```

now if I need to access the Customer name attribute from the lhs and use it in the insert operation in rhs, how would I modify the above transform function to achieve the same.

I need to write a transform function that should spit out a rule something similar to below.

```
(defrule temperature-alert
  "Issue a temperature alert. This rule joins the current temperature with the location
   and gathers additional information to fire an alert with context."
  [CurrentTemperature (> value high-threshold)
                      (= ?location-id location)
                      (= ?value value)]

  [Location (= ?location-id id)
            (= ?sector sector)]
  =>
  (alert-temperature! ?value ?location-id ?sector))
```